# Adding $ to dynamically created string and evaluating with isset as variable

Tags: php

I am having a bit of trouble figuring this one out, basically I have a string being created dynamically and passed through a couple functions, I want to add a "$" to the front of the string to make it a variable and then evaluate it as such with isset()...

Am I missing an obvious way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for variable variable:

```
$string = 'b';
$b = 'Test';
if(isset($$string)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Note that this is usually a frowned upon practice as in a larger code base, you'll get headache later trying to figure out where `$b` is coming from

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `$$` variable variable construction, note that you can also use the bracket syntax (although it's terribly ugly) to create variables using strings:

```
${'myVar'} = 42;
echo $myVar; // 42
echo "${myVar}"; // 42

$val = 'myVar';
${$val} = 'the answer';
echo $myVar; // the answer (not 42)
```

Comment: Thanks for this technique as well

Answer (score -1):

Put addslash function before the "$" symbol because it takes as the variable. By using the addslash function it takes as the special character.